# keyboard.read_key() records 2 events

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm trying something:
When I press a key, I want a counter to increase and add the current timestamp
problem is: I get 2 events for whenever I press a key, any idea?

```
import keyboard
from datetime import datetime

running = True
counter = 0
while running:
    input = keyboard.read_key()
    if input== "esc":
        print (counter)
        running = False
    else:
        counter += 1
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
        print(counter,dateTimeObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably registering both key down and key up. You can use an auxiliary variable to only register it once:

```
import keyboard
from datetime import datetime

running = True
counter = 0
not_pressed = True
while running:
    input = keyboard.read_key(suppress = True)
    if input== "esc":
        print (counter)
        running = False
    else:
        if not_pressed:
            counter += 1
            dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
            print(counter,dateTimeObj)
            not_pressed = False
        else:
            not_pressed = True
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your program is registering events when you are pressing the key and when you
releasing the key?

maybe the `keyboard.record()` will help you

```
# Record events until 'esc' is pressed.
recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')
```

here is [the description to keyboard module](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

As Miguel says `keyboard.read_key` registers both key down and key up.

Using `keyboard.read_event` saved my day.

In the context of provided code `keyboard.read_event` can be used and `continue` the loop if it's a `keyup` event

```
import keyboard
from datetime import datetime

running = True
counter = 0

while running:
    key_event = keyboard.read_event(suppress=True)

    if key_event.event_type == "up":
        continue

    if key_event.name == "esc":
        print(counter)
        running = False
    else:
        counter += 1
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
        print(counter, dateTimeObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can do this :

```
import keyboard
from datetime import datetime

running = True
counter = 0
while running:
    # Wait for the next event.
    event = keyboard.read_event(
        suppress=True
    )  # will not show a lot of new lines (if 'enter' pushed)
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        if event.name == "esc":
            print(counter)
            running = False
        else:
            counter += 1
            dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
            print(counter, dateTimeObj)
```