# Python Keyboard module detects the pressed key more than once

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a keylogger with the 'Keyboard' module in Python, the troubble is that the  read_key() function is returning the same pressed key many times.

```
import keyboard as kb

cadena = ''

while True:
    key = kb.read_key()
    if len(key) == 1:
        cadena +=key
        print(cadena)
```

**I just wrote "Hello world"**

but this code returns:

```
h
hh
hhe
hhee
hheel
hheell
hheelll
hheellll
hheellllo
hheelllloo
hheelllloow
hheelllloowo
hheelllloowow
hheelllloowowo
hheelllloowowor
hheelllloowoworr
hheelllloowoworrl
hheelllloowoworrll
hheelllloowoworrlld
hheelllloowoworrlldd
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keyboard.read\_key() records 2 events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891390/keyboard-read-key-records-2-events)

Comment: Depending on what you are doing `cadena=keyboard.record(until="enter"); keyboard.play(cadena)` may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keyboard.record` to record all keyboard activity until a specified key is pressed. After this you can either replay the activity or print particular events (e.g. down press events):

```
import keyboard

text = ""

rec = keyboard.record(until='Enter')

# Either this
keyboard.play(rec)

# Or this
for event in rec:
    if event.event_type == "down":
        text += event.name
print(text)
```